# How to align faces and edges on x, y and z axis ? Blender 2.8

Tags: modeling

I want to align some faces
 But it seems no one knows

Comment: This is done the same way as in previous versions: Select the faces you want. To align in the X axis, press S X 0 (zero). To align on Y axis press S Y 0, On Z axis is the same: S Z 0

Comment: I'm max user. Thanks